# Integration with Google (OAuth)

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I'm planning on building a G suite integration with my existing SaaS site.

I want Gsuite admins to allow access for their organisation.  So I only want "domain install" possible.

After this has been done users can be imported from Google into our application. Users should be able to use SSO to login but I don't want each user having to pass the consent screen.

I also want the app to have readonly access to the calendar of the user.

What is confusing for me: do I need to create a regular web app integration or a Service account integration?  I don't really need offline access but I want to avoid all users having to grant access individually.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/building#meet_g_suite_marketplace_standards) it says: *The user sees the OAuth Consent screen only once; if you’re using a service account to allow a domain admin accept terms on behalf of the domain users, then the end users must never see the OAuth consent screen.*

So does that mean only service accounts allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a service account you can install and authorize one app for all your domain user impersonating the admin account. In such a way, your users won't have to authorize the app individually.

You will have to enable [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) in order to impersonate the admin account when using a service account.

### Reference

[Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)